# Scala -Spark - Iterate over joined pair RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to join 2 PairRDD in spark and not sure how to iterate over the result.

```
val input1 = sc.textFile(inputFile1)
val input2 = sc.textFile(inputFile2)

val pairs = input1.map(x => (x.split("\\|")(18),x))
val groupPairs = pairs.groupByKey()

val staPairs = input2.map(y => (y.split("\\|")(0),y))
val stagroupPairs = staPairs.groupByKey()

val finalJoined = groupPairs.leftOuterJoin(stagroupPairs)
```

finalJoined is of type finalJoined:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Iterable[String], Option[Iterable[String]]))]
```

When I do `finalJoined.collect().foreach(println)` I see the below output  :

```
(key1,(CompactBuffer(val1a,val1b),Some(CompactBuffer(val1)))
(key2,(CompactBuffer(val2a,val2b),Some(CompactBuffer(val2)))
```

I would like the output to be

for **key1**

```
val1a+"|"+val1

val1b+"|"+val1
```

for **key2**

```
val2a+"|"+val2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avoid groupByKey step on both the rdds and perform join on directly pairs and starpairs..you will get the desired result.

For e.g,

```
    val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array("key1,val1a","key1,val1b","key2,val2a","key2,val2b").toSeq)
 val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array("key1,val1","key2,val2").toSeq)
 val pairs= rdd1.map(_.split(",")).map(x => (x(0),x(1)))
val starPairs= rdd2.map(_.split(",")).map(x => (x(0),x(1)))
val res = pairs.join(starPairs)
res.foreach(println)

(key1,(val1a,val1))
(key1,(val1b,val1))
(key2,(val2a,val2))
(key2,(val2b,val2))
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed groupBy and with extra formatting got expected result.